# Unity Container - How to correctly resolve a parameterised MemoryCache that's registered as a singleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, memorycache

Despite Unity container being deprecated, unfortunately I find myself having to use it since the current wpf codebase I'm working on has been dependent on it for years.

On the server side, I'm able to just do

```
public void ConfigureServices ( IServiceCollection services )
{
    ...
    services.AddMemoryCache (memoryCacheOptions =>
    {
        memoryCacheOptions.SizeLimit = 2;
        memoryCacheOptions.TrackStatistics = true;
    } 
}
```

and then start using my DI member in the constructor of a Manager class

```
public class ClassManager
{
    ...

    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;
    
    ...
    
    public ClassManager ( ... , IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        ...
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
        ...
    }

}
```

I'm looking to implement some light caching on my wpf client that uses the Unity Container for DI. I've been trying to inject MemoryCache like this

```
...
{
    this.Container.RegisterType<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache> (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager ());
    var optionsAccessor = new MemoryCacheOptions
            {
                SizeLimit = 2,
                TrackStatistics = true
            };
    this.Container.Resolve<IMemoryCache> (new ParameterOverride[] { new ("optionsAccessor", optionsAccessor ) });
}
```

It seems that the type registering is fine but however when it comes to resolving it, I get an error that says

> Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution failed with error: Failed to select a constructor for Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache
>
> For more detailed information run Unity in debug mode: new UnityContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic())'
>
> InvalidOperationException: Failed to select a constructor for Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache
>
> InvalidRegistrationException: Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, as the MemoryCache's ctor takes in an argument of `IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions>`, and I'm overriding the parameter to feed in a `MemoryCacheOptions` object, which already implements the `<IOptions>` interface.

You can find the MemoryCache ctor here: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register using the factory method

```
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterFactory<IMemoryCache>( 
        c =>
        {
            var optionsAccessor = new MemoryCacheOptions
            {
                SizeLimit = 2,
                TrackStatistics = true
            };
            return new MemoryCache( optionsAccessor );
        }, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );

    var cache = container.Resolve<IMemoryCache>();
```